# Rectangles in a figure

Tags: puzzle

I have this figure [image: Figure]

and I have to find $5$ rectangles (which includes squares).

I just see four.
[image]

Where is the $5^{th}$ rectangle?

Comment: What about the square middle top?

Comment: Could you be more specific? @AndréNicolas

Comment: There are no labels to use in a description. Note there is a square with completely filled in sides. It is the first square you bump into when you are going down from the top of the screen.

Comment: As to drawing a line, complete the cross by drawing a short horizontal line, we end up with $11$ rectangles.

Comment: Consider a coordinate system with origin in the top left of the diagram; then the rectangles you've specified can be described (using minimum and maximum (x,y) coordinates) as (0,1)..(2,2), (3,1)..(5,2), (2,0)..(3,3), and (2,1)..(3,3).  Andre's additional rectangle (square) is (2,0)..(3,1).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kv6yaU8.png

Comment: Thanks all!
finally understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Top: $1$
- Bottom : $2$
- Left : $3$
- Right: $4$
- Middle: $5$ (combination of $1$ and $2$)